# Typo3 messed up after backup restore

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

I fumbled around with an ancient T3 installation (tried an upgrade from 4.5 to 6.2) and before the fumbling created a backup from the entire directory on the webserver as well as the database.

Now I tried to re-activate that backup (a.k.a. 4.5). The install tool works fine, DB-Connection seems to be ok, but when I try to access the backend, it tries to access `/typo3/sysext/install/Start/Install.php` which isn't present at the described location.

I tried to delete all caches, emptied the typo3temp folder - nothing helps. It seems there's something stuck from the upgrade process, but I have no idea where.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem's solved. T3 6.2 uses the PHP Opcode Cache which can't be reset in the 4.5 install tool. Something must have been stuck there. I wrote a little PHP script that clears the cache and viola, it worked.

`opcache_reset();`